# Does Powershot Canon G5 X Mark ii has clean hdmi output WITH auto focus and auto mode?

Tags: canon, powershot

I've read the manual and saw that there is clean hdmi output. But I would like to confirm that with works with auto focus (without that square) and auto mode (auto iso, auto F and so forth).

Comment: Maybe you can ask your question on [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com)